# How to filter a type of user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working a particular web application. I have made use of the Django Abstract user has my application has different types of user. I have the admin user as well as the bar owner.

I need to return the number of bar owners in the application but don't know how to go about it.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
class UserType(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_landlord = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Note**: I need to be able to return the number of is_landlord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For returning the no. of users who are landords you can use the query
UserType.objects.filter(is_landlord=True).count()